# Abort all instances of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, abort, thread-abort

I have this line of code that calls the function `SigWebRefresh` at specified intervals (`50` milliseconds).

```
tmr = setInterval(SigWebRefresh, 50);
```

`SigWebRefresh` performs `XMLHTTPRequest`:

```
function SigWebRefresh(){   
    xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xhr2.open("GET", baseUri + "SigImage/0", true );
    xhr2.responseType = "blob"; 
    xhr2.onload = function (){
        var img = new Image();      
        img.src = getBlobURL(xhr2.response);        
        img.onload = function (){           
           Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
           revokeBlobURL( img.src );
           img = null;
        }
    }   
    xhr2.send(null);
}
```

I had use `clearInterval` that clears a timer set with the setInterval() method.

```
 clearInterval(tmr);
```

I want to abort all XMLHttpRequest but `xhr2.abort();` only aborts one instance of the request. How to abort all uncompleted `XmlHttpRequest` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pushing each `xhr2` variable to an array , utilize `Array.prototype.forEach` to abort each `xhr2` variable stored

```
var requests = [];

function SigWebRefresh(){   
    xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requests.push(xhr2);    
    xhr2.open("GET", baseUri + "SigImage/0", true );
    xhr2.responseType = "blob"; 
    xhr2.onload = function (){
        var img = new Image();      
        img.src = getBlobURL(xhr2.response);        
        img.onload = function (){           
           Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
           revokeBlobURL( img.src );
           img = null;
        }
    }   
    xhr2.send(null);
}

// abort all requests
requests.forEach(function(request) {
  request.abort()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a list of all the processing requests:

```
function remove(array, element){
    var index = array.indexOf(element);
    if (index > -1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

var all_requests = [] // The list of requests that are processing
function SigWebRefresh(){   
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xhr2.open("GET", baseUri + "SigImage/0", true );
    xhr2.responseType = "blob"; 
    xhr2.onload = function (){
        var img = new Image();      
        img.src = getBlobURL(xhr2.response);        
        img.onload = function (){           
           Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
           revokeBlobURL( img.src );
           img = null;
           remove(all_requests, xhr2); // Make sure to remove already finished requests from your list
        }
    }   
    xhr2.send(null);
    all_requests.push(xhr2); // Add processing request to the list
}
```

And then to clear:

```
for(var i in all_requests)
    all_requests[i].abort();
all_requests = [] // Clear the list of requests
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var xhr2 = null;

 function SigWebRefresh(){  
      if( xhr2 != null ) {
            xhr2.abort();
            xhr2 = null;
      }
      xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();    
      xhr2.open("GET", baseUri + "SigImage/0", true );
      xhr2.responseType = "blob"; 
      xhr2.onload = function (){
        var img = new Image();      
        img.src = getBlobURL(xhr2.response);        
        img.onload = function (){           
           Ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
           revokeBlobURL( img.src );
           img = null;
        }
     }   
     xhr2.send(null);
 }
```

Comment: When you call SigWebRefresh the previous xhr2 will be aborted.